# Strange error with text file in C

Tags: c, windows, file-io

I had to learn the basic of C langague for scool. So, it means that I'm still a noob. However, a strange thing happened after I created my code. The basic of my code is to create a text file with number, then in an other text file, reverse these numbers.

Here is my code :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LIGNE 80

int main()
{
    char ligne[MAX_LIGNE] = {0};
    FILE* fdFichierentree;
    FILE* fdFichiersortie;

int *tableau =0;
int termine = 0;
char * nomFichierEntree = "entreeTexte.txt";

if ((fdFichierentree = fopen(nomFichierEntree, "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Creation de %s impossible\n", nomFichierEntree);
    _getch();
    exit(0);
}

char * nomFichierSortie = "sortieTexte.txt";

if ((fdFichiersortie = fopen(nomFichierSortie, "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("lecture de %s impossible\n", nomFichierSortie);
    _getch();
    exit(0);
}



while (!termine)
{
    printf("(E)ntree le ou les nombres ou (Q)uitter\n");
    switch (_getch())
    {
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
        printf("entrer les nombres :");
        fgets(ligne, MAX_LIGNE, stdin);
        fprintf(fdFichierentree, "%s", ligne);
        break;
    case 'q':
    case'Q':
        termine = 1;
        break;
    }

}




int nb = 0;
while (fgets(ligne, MAX_LIGNE, fdFichierentree))
    ++nb;

tableau = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*nb);
rewind(fdFichierentree);

nb = 0;
while (fgets(ligne, MAX_LIGNE, fdFichierentree))
{
    tableau[nb++] = atoi(ligne);
}

int i;
for (i = nb - 1; i > -1; --i)
    fprintf(fdFichiersortie, "%d\n", tableau[i]);



fclose(fdFichierentree);
fclose(fdFichiersortie);

}
```

The strange thing appears in the file texte. For example, if I write 10 and 20 as numbers, the file text will have both numbers, but also 80 - n of strange i where n is the numbers I have chosen. In my example, I will have the numbers 10 and 20 and also 80 - 2, so 78 i in the rest of my text file.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

there are some parts in my code that is in french which is normal because I'm french. Sorry about that.

I hope someone could find my error in my code !

Comment: How many unknown i constitute a shitload?

Comment: Sorry. *a shit load of unknown i* is not a useful problem description. This is a site for technical questions; you're not chatting with your buddies in the *scool* yard. Please [edit] post and be **specific** about the problem you're having with the code you dumped (pun intended) here. Better yet, take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages (especially [ask]) first. Then when you [edit], you can do it correctly and avoid the juvenile profanity that may not be acceptable to all people here.

Comment: did you print out nb to check its value? you opened a file for write, then read from it without closing and reopening it. that might be the problem.

Comment: `tableau = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*nb);` -->> `tableau = malloc(nb * sizeof *tableau);`

Comment: I just try it and it didn't work, still do the same. I'll try to look at nb like shiping told. ty

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when displaying an error message, display it on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using `perror()` rather than `printf()` as the reason the OS thinks the error occurred will also be displayed.

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is not a C standard header, so any code using it will be non-portable.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
if ((fdFichierentree = fopen(nomFichierEntree, "w")) == NULL)
```

opens the file ONLY for write.

So using the same `fdFichierentree` for reading will not work.

Suggest:

```
if ((fdFichierentree = fopen(nomFichierEntree, "w+")) == NULL)
```

so can also read from the file.